# Multiple array data in php and get the SUM

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter and I have a function like this .

```
function total_income(){    
        $data['total_income'] = $this->mod_products->total_income();
        echo"<pre>";
        print_r($data['total_income']);    
}
```

The above code return an array like this.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [sub_product_price] => 1000
            [quantity] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [sub_product_price] => 1000
            [quantity] => 1
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [sub_product_price] => 50
            [quantity] => 15
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [sub_product_price] => 500
            [quantity] => 5
        )
)
```

Now I want to get the `[sub_product_price]` and **multiply** that value with `[quantity]` .Then I want to get the `array_sum`. I don't have an idea how to do that. Could some one help me It would be grate ,

Cheers!! Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the all values after multiplication in an `empty array` and use **`array_sum()`** to get the final value.

```
$temp = array();
foreach($data['total_income'] as $in)
{
    $temp[] = $in->sub_product_price * $in->quantity;
}

$total = array_sum($temp);
```

**Explanation:**

**`array_sum()`** returns the sum of all the values of an array.

Example,

```
$array = array(4,5,6);
echo array_sum($array);    // 15
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$sum = 0;
foreach ($array as $obj) {
    $sum += ($obj->quantity * $obj->sub_product_price);
}
```